# How to change border color of a Lightning Data Table column based on date value in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

I have a Lightning Web Component (LWC) with a Lightning Data Table that displays data, including a date column. I want to change the border color of the date column to red if the date has passed.

I tried using conditional formatting by setting the cellAttributes property for the date column, but it does not work, i am able to change the text color but the border is not coming.

Is there a way to achieve this in LWC? Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Unless you use a custom data type (maybe you should) you have to pick an existing style that would typically by applied to the slds element type you are using. For example, you could try `slds-theme_error` as a class to apply to these cells. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that using LoadStyle

Repo Link :

https://github.com/karykaran/DataTableCssDemo.git

You can add your own condition to show border.I hope that will work for you

Result :

[image]